# JMeter JSON Path extractor

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I use JMeter 4, I have a problem in a JMeter JSON Path Extractor. 
I have done an HTTP Request (POST) to a service that I wan't to test.

Response data from the service is

```
{"rid":"661ff2d7-12e8-e811-8110-00215a9b9851",
 "participation":{"rid":"ed8cfced-0063-4fda-92fd-b23f50197797"}}
```

I wan't to extract the first GUID witch is allocated to the first rid.

As JSONPath Expression I have used $.rid and wan't to assign that value to a JMeter variable. Therefore I have checked the radio button JMeter variable and entered my JMeter variable which is int_rid.

When I execute my JMeter testplan the int_rid variable will be null.

Comment: You can upvote if the answer was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) If you check the radio button JMeter variable it expect to search inside the contents  of JMeter variable, which you don't want, usually Main sample only is enough

> Main sample only - only applies to the main sample
>
> Sub-samples only - only applies to the sub-samples
>
> Main sample and sub-samples - applies to both.
>
> JMeter Variable Name to use - assertion is to be applied to the contents of the named variable

Put `int_rid` in `Names of created variables` field and chose Match No. `1` to find the first value